# .NET Framework: Get Type from TypeInfo

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-core

The new reflection API introduces the `TypeInfo` class:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.typeinfo

I can get a `TypeInfo` instance of a `Type` (say, a `Car`) by writing

```
TypeInfo typeInfo = typeof(Car).GetTypeInfo();
```

Now, what if I just have a `TypeInfo` instance? How do I get the `Type` it's referring to? Can I just write

```
Type type = typeInfo.GetType();
```

Or will this return a `type` that is equal to `typeof(TypeInfo)`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you call `typeInfo.GetType()`, you will indeed get the execution-time type of the object that `typeInfo` refers to - so some concrete type derived from `TypeInfo`.

You want [`TypeInfo.AsType()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.typeinfo.astype#System_Reflection_TypeInfo_AsType):

> Returns the current type as a Type object.

So your code would be:

```
Type type = typeInfo.AsType();
```

Or, as noted in comments, something I'd never noticed: `TypeInfo` derives from `Type`! So just use:

```
Type type = typeInfo;
```

Comment: *If you call `typeInfo.GetType()`, you will indeed get `typeof(TypeInfo)`.* I would expect it would give you `RuntimeType` rather then abstract `TypeInfo`.

Comment: Since `TypeInfo` already inherits from `Type`, what's the advantage to calling `AsType()`?

Comment: @RobSiklos: Do you know, I had never noticed that... I suspect it's for cases where you want to chain and *only* want the compile-time type to be `Type`, like `AsEnumerable()` in LINQ.

Comment: Is `TypeInfo` something that's only available with DebugInformation enabled, or somethings that can be relied on in production code?

Comment: @Daniel: It should always be available.